# Command-P 'paste script/shortcut'

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I am using a mac, and I usually paste things in by doing the following:

- `:set paste!`
- <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>
- `:set paste!`

This is really the only way I've been able to paste things into vim reliably (with the help of iTerm), whether it's on a local or remote server (i.e., on a remote server having `"a` yanked locally means nothing). I was wondering if there was some way to automate this behavior, either in `vim` or outside it. I don't think it's possible entirely in vim, as it doesn't recognize mac's <kbd>cmd</kbd> character. What might be a good way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean the other way around? `:set paste` before Cmd+P and `:set nopaste` after it?

Comment: @filbranden yes, good spot thank you. Normally I'll just do `paste!` but yes I mixed them up (fixed now)

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the paste mappings from [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) by Tim Pope, which will drop you on insert mode under `set paste` and restore `nopaste` as soon as you leave insert mode.

The [mappings](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired/blob/master/doc/unimpaired.txt#L108) are:

- `[op`: Paste above the current line (similar to `O` but with `set paste`)
- `]op`: Paste below the current line (similar to `o` but with `set paste`)
- `yop`: Paste replacing the current line (similar to `S` but with `set paste`)

So one could use the sequence:

- `]op`
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>

Since leaving Insert mode with "Esc" is enough to restore `nopaste` mode.

But I also like to paste from when I'm *already* in Insert mode, for example if I want to write something above the text I'm about to paste.

For that, I use the following mapping:

```
inoremap <C-e> <C-g>u<C-o>:normal <Plug>unimpairedPaste<cr>
```

This will use the Ctrl+E key in Insert mode to switch to `set paste` mode, while setting up the restoring of `nopaste` after leaving Insert mode. It reuses the internal mapping from vim-unimpaired. Before setting up for pasting, it issues a [`<C-g>u`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-G_u) sequence, to break the "undo" tree, meaning you can undo the paste operation on its own, without undoing the additional text you wrote before your paste.

So then the sequence is:

- `i` (or similar), to enter Insert mode
- enter any text that should precede the paste
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, to `set paste`
- <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, to actually paste the contents of the clipboard
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>, to leave Insert mode

Answer (score 1):

There is something called "bracketed paste mode", see `:h xterm-bracketed-paste`. 
Check if iTerm supports it. If it does, make sure you don't unset `t_BE` and `t_BD` in your configuration. (I don't have a Mac, so I can't test.)

If that doesn't work: I have configures <kbd>F9</kbd> to toggle paste mode:

```
set pastetoggle=<F9>    " toggle paste option
```

Comment: You shouldnt need the mappings with pastetoggle set

Comment: @D.BenKnoble you're right. Those three lines in my vimrc are at least 10 years old.  Updating (the answer and my vimrc :-))

Comment: @Ralf looks like it does, thanks for the tip: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/wikis/Paste-Bracketing

Comment: @David542 Tell us if it works or not and what you had to do.