# Problem pasting text with brackets when using auto-close functions/plugins

Tags: cut-copy-paste

It's nice to have an auto-close plugin for brackets and quotes like `coc-pairs`. However, when I paste text from outside into vim insert (`ctrl-C`, `ctrl-shift-v`), the text seems to be pasted character-by-character. As a result, vim inserts extra quotes and brackets and messes up the copied texts.

Example:

```
Copied text:
(this is a test)

Result:
(this is a test))
```

This behavior gets annoying really fast, especially when trying to copy code. This is currently the only reason I'm not using an auto-close plugin.

How can I fix this behavior to make vim copy text as a whole block without making any change to such copied texts?

Comment: That's odd. Independently of `'paste'` value, usually auto-pairing plugings jump over the next closing `)` when typing it. Isn't it the case of the plugin you're using?

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to fix this is to enable the [`'paste'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27paste%27) option before pasting external text into Vim.

Enabling `'paste'` will disable options that usually mangle input, such as autoindent or expandtab, but it also disables all insert mode mappings (which is how auto-closing brackets is implemented.) So pasting external text with `'paste'` enabled will prevent Vim settings and plug-ins from modifying the external pasted text.

See [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/24928/18609) for some recommendations on how to enable paste for a single paste, so it gets disabled automatically after you're finished pasting, re-enabling the behavior that is useful while you're interactively inserting text, such as auto-closing brackets.

The linked question also has an answer that covers [bracketed paste](https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html#xterm-bracketed-paste), which is a way to configure Vim and your terminal so that your terminal can indicate to Vim that a set of characters is a paste and Vim can automatically handle them the same as if the `'paste'` option is enabled. (Essentially, it makes Vim "recognize" text that is coming through a `Ctrl+Shift+V`.)